# PHP MySQL select all column order

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple test table

```
|id|name|colour|
```

When I use MySQL workbench and run

`SELECT * FROM table`

columns are returned in this order
`id, name, colour`

Using PHP and PDO (fetchall, `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`) when I run the exact same query, columns are returned in this order

`name, id, colour`

id is even a pkey/auto increment. I know I can manually do the select to maintain order, but, I want to understand why this is happening.

---

While I don't know the answer to my own question, it's worth mentioning that using `PDO::FETCH_NUM` returns columns in the correct order.

Comment: try SELECT id, name, colour FROM table

Comment: If you expect the columns to be in a particular order, you _must_ specify them in the `SELECT` list. It is not often a good idea to `SELECT *` in production code for exactly these reasons. It is really up to the client API as to how the columns will be presented to you if you aren't explicit about it. Though I would _expect_ PDO to use the same order (the order in the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output), it does not need to respect that if not instructed to.